# How to find out which activity has been loaded

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have 3 activities. A, B and C. From A to C and B to C. How can i from Activity C find out which activity was loaded previously and refereed to this Activity.

Comment: You can send  some value as `Bundle` to determine that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle this through intent bundles. Basically in Activity A or B you launch Activity C as follows:

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
launchIntent.putExtra("originActivity", this.getClass().getName());
```

In Activity C, you retrieve it like

```
public class ActivityC extends Activity{
   onCreate(...){
      Intent callingIntent = getIntent();

      String originActivity = callingIntent.getStringExtra("originActivity");

   }
}
```

Now I passed the activity name as string, you may include it in some more convenient way, using constants or something like that. You can look it up [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you start your activity C with startActivityForResult instead of startActivity, you have access to the calling Activity:

Start Activity C like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class);
int requestCode = 1; // Or some other integer
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

in Activity C:

```
onCreate(...) {
  String callingClassName = getCallingActivity().getClass().getSimpleName();
}
```

Comment: Yep, that'd be another approach, however only if activity C is intended to fetch some result for the previous ones....